# RabbitMQ - Get messages from a queue using curl

Tags: linux, curl, rabbitmq

I am trying to get a few messages from a queue using the HTTP API of rabbitmq.

I am following the documentation in [here](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/priv/www/api/index.html)
I have no `vhost` configured.

I tried the following curl command:

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/foo/get -d'{"count":5,"requeue":true,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}'
```

RabbitMQ then answers:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
vary: origin
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 08:03:28 GMT
Content-Length: 66
Allow: HEAD, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

{"error":"Method Not Allowed","reason":"\"Method Not Allowed\"\n"}
```

Can you point out my mistake? How can I get these messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The key:

> I have no vhost configured.

RabbitMQ uses the "/" notation for the default VHOST.

[image]

"/" is translated to `%2F` in HTTP...

So the correct call is:

```
curl -u guest:guest -i -H "content-type:application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2F/foo/get -d'{"count":5,"requeue":true,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}'
```

Answer (score 10):

you are missing the queue name:

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/foo/my_queue/get -d'{"count":5,"requeue":true,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}'
```

where `foo` is the virtual host, and `my_queue` is the queue name.

as result:

```
[
   {
      "payload_bytes":4,
      "redelivered":true,
      "exchange":"",
      "routing_key":"my_queue",
      "message_count":5,
      "properties":{
         "delivery_mode":1,
         "headers":{

         }
      },
      "payload":"test",
      "payload_encoding":"string"
   },
   {
      "payload_bytes":4,
      "redelivered":true,
      "exchange":"",
      "routing_key":"my_queue",
      "message_count":4,
      "properties":{
         "delivery_mode":1,
         "headers":{

         }
      },
      "payload":"test",
      "payload_encoding":"string"
   },
   {
      "payload_bytes":4,
      "redelivered":true,
      "exchange":"",
      "routing_key":"my_queue",
      "message_count":3,
      "properties":{
         "delivery_mode":1,
         "headers":{

         }
      },
      "payload":"test",
      "payload_encoding":"string"
   },
   {
      "payload_bytes":4,
      "redelivered":true,
      "exchange":"",
      "routing_key":"my_queue",
      "message_count":2,
      "properties":{
         "delivery_mode":1,
         "headers":{

         }
      },
      "payload":"test",
      "payload_encoding":"string"
   },
   {
      "payload_bytes":4,
      "redelivered":true,
      "exchange":"",
      "routing_key":"my_queue",
      "message_count":1,
      "properties":{
         "delivery_mode":1,
         "headers":{

         }
      },
      "payload":"test",
      "payload_encoding":"string"
   }
]
```

**EDIT**

In case you are using the default vhost:

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2f/my_queue/get -d'{"count":5,"requeue":true,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}'
```

Comment: Can I somehow add the filter ? for example get messages filtering by headers or properties ?

Comment: Again, No it is not possible, as I said: `you can consume one message at a time in FIFO way` :)!

Answer (score 9):

Note that the syntax seems to have changed in more recent releases (and the HTTP API documentation seems to be lagging behind) and instead of the `requeue` option the `ack_mode` option needs to be set, e.g. `"ack_mode":"ack_requeue_true"`

So the example above for current RabbitMQ versions would be:

```
curl -u guest:guest -i -H "content-type:application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2F/foo/get -d'{"count":5,"ack_mode":"ack_requeue_true","encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}'
```

Comment: It need to be  {"ackmode":"ack_requeue_true"} not  {"ack_mode"="ack_requeue_true"}, otherwise you'll get not json error.

Comment: Little detail: But I'd like to point out that the answer of Akos it says "ack_mode" and in Semooze reply it's "ackmode" without the underscore, for those that are blind like me. I was getting {"error":"bad_request","reason":"[{key_missing,ackmode}]"} and didn't realize for a while that there's no underscore.

Comment: provided json has a error, so this is you use
-d'{"count":5,"ackmode":"ack_requeue_true","requeue":
true,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}'

Comment: Thanks all, I fixed the JSON (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that [the documentation](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.11/priv/www/api/index.html) says the following about this endpoint :

> Please note that the get path in the HTTP API is intended for diagnostics etc - it does not implement reliable delivery and so should be treated as a sysadmin's tool rather than a general API for messaging.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get messages and save them in a file, you can use the ["Get RabbitMQ messages"](https://pypi.org/project/rabbitgetapi/) package for this.

Install:

```
pip install rabbitgetapi
```

Example:

```
$ rabbitgetapi getqueue -f <path/fileconf.yaml> -o <outputfile> -c 1000 -s =

Where (get dlq messages):
  path/fileconf.yaml = Configuration file (In this example, the server credentials)
  outputfile = File where the message will be saved  
  c = Counter
  s = Seperator
```

The configuration file content:

```
url: 
 https://f-9e14acc7-ef3c-4a2f-a829-c96a7c8c691f.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
 
user: 
 login-user
 
password: 
 the-secret-password
 
queue: 
 DLQ_QUEUE
 
count: 
 100
```