# Push JSON file (messages) to queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: json, curl, rabbitmq

Let's say I have two queues i.e. `queue1` and `queue2`. I have messages in `queue1` which I stored in a JSON file by using the following command.

```
curl -u user:pass -H "content-type:application/json" -XPOST http://192.168.178.23:15672/api/queues/testvhost/queue1/get -d'{"count":5,"ackmode":"ack_requeue_true","encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}' -o m1.json
```

with the help of this post:- [RabbitMQ - Get messages from a queue using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513681/rabbitmq-get-messages-from-a-queue-using-curl)

My JSON file looks like this:- https://paste-me.net/fibed

I am trying to push this JSON file (messages) to another queue `queue2` with the help of the following command:

```
curl -i -u user:pass -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d @m1.json http://192.168.178.23:15672/api/exchanges/testvhost/queue2/publish

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
content-length: 0
```

But it seems to be not working.

Any help will be appreciated and please don't suggest to me an idea about the shovel.

ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation, in order to publish a message using HTTP, the body should look like this:

```
{"properties":{},"routing_key":"my key","payload":"my body","payload_encoding":"string"}
```

But you are sending an array of messages, which seems to be not supported in the API (as it states it expects a single message with these fields).

[image]

https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/priv/www/api/index.html